# Checking several values/strings/variables for a pair of phrases in python 3.3

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 52 keys:values, like a pack of cards. I need to check in an 'if' statement if there are two or more values (cards) with the same phrase in. I need this to be a function so I can call it several times.

In short, I need the code to recognise a 'pair' of cards, like in texas hold 'em, but I don't want it to recognise the same value (card) twice.
So far I have tried (I'm not sure for the correct syntax, pretty much psuedocode):

```
def cintelpair3(a, b, c, d, e):
    if any 2 'Ace' or 'Two' in(a, b, c, d, e):
        print("You have a pair")
```

Assume variables a through e have been assigned strings from the dictionary already, so treat them as if they are strings; because they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If function arguments is strings you can do it like this:

```
def cintelpair3(a, b, c, d, e):
    if any([a, b, c, d, e].count(card) == 2 for card in ['Ace', 'Two']):
        print("You have a pair")
```

or this way for any number of args:

```
def cintelpair3(*args):
    if any(args.count(card) == 2 for card in ['Ace', 'Two']):
        print("You have a pair")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply also, will look into this option, it seems like a likely option.

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd be more convenient to put your 5 arguments in a list. Then, the function would work for any size hand. The cards you want matched can go into a list, `matching_cards`, which would also work for any size.

Python's for-else syntax will work very well for this type of application:

```
def matching(hand, matching_cards):
    for card in matching_cards:
        if card not in hand:
            print("Nothing found!") # Every card needs to be in the hand
            break
    else: # Every card was found in hand, break never executed
        print("Match detected!")
```

This function will work if you're looking for exact string matches. However, if you want to match parts of strings in the hand (e.g. you're using short words like `"Two"` to match cards like `"Two of Spades"` and `"Two of Hearts"`) then the function is more advanced. I see two ways to go about this:

```
def matching(hand, matching_phrases):
    for phrase in matching_phrases:
        for card in hand:
            if phrase in card: # Phrase must be in string of at least one card
                break # Once phrase is found in one string, break
        else: # Otherwise, phrase was never found in any of the cards. No match
            print("Nothing found!")
            break
    else: # Every phrase was found in hand, break never executed
        print("Match detected!")
```

or, using a style more similar to @ndpu. For each `phrase` in `matching_phrases`, this function checks if `any` of the `card`s contains the `phrase`. For the `if` statement to be executed, `all` `phrase`s must be in one of the cards.

```
def matching(hand, matching_phrases):
    if all(any(phrase in card for card in hand) for phrase in matching_phrases):
        print("Match detected!")
    else:
        print("Nothing found!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into this as it seems much more efficient and viable than my current setup.

Comment: @Russman see edit, the first function may not be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thankyou for adding that edit, you are correct and I want to match parts of strings, just noticed that in your first option! Those two you suggested along with the ones from ndpu are what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following dict:

```
your_dict = {
    'ace1': 1,
    'ace2': 1,
    ...
    'two1': 2,
    'two2': 2,
    ...
}
```

You could:

```
import random
hand_values = {}
# Returns a list of 5 (your_dict's VALUES)
random_five = random.sample(list(your_dict.values()), 5)
for card in random_five:
    if card in hand_values:
        hand_values[card] += 1
    else:
        hand_values[card] = 1
```

Which would result in something like:

```
hand_values = {1: 2, 4: 2, 7: 1}
```

The above is saying: Your have includes 2 cards whose value is 1 (two Ace cards), 2 cards whose value is 4 (two 4 cards) and one card whose value is 7 (one Seven card)

You then need to have a dict (presumably), which contains the possible hands (pairs, full house, etc.) and do something along the lines of what jmu303 recommended.

This of course ignores the fact that you'll need to compare individual's hands to see who wins ;)